# Show loader without blocking the user in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, mobile, sencha-touch

In my Sencha Touch application, I want to show the loader but I don't want to block the user from interacting with the application. Is there some flag that I can set to accomplish this. I am showing loader using this command-

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
        xtype: 'loadmask',
        indicator: true,
        message: ''
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard loading mask in Touch/Ext is designed to prevent user interaction while loading so it is not configurable to behave otherwise.

You could show a spinner icon somewhere on the screen without blocking the user access but it cannot be the standard loading mask.